# Make programs and profiles use D:\ by default

Tags: windows-server-2003

I've just had to set up an install of Windows Server 2003 (SP2) as a Terminal Server (due to compatibility issues with a program we use), and I'm looking to make some changes.

By default, all programs are installed to `C:\Program Files` and all user profiles are stored in `C:\Documents and Settings`. Is it possible to change the settings on the server so that `D:\` is used for this data instead (by default, without having to manually change the directory for every install)? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: So that no one has access to `C:` via the TS, but users can see `D:` (and according to their permissions, do stuff).